# g++ compilation error on AIX unix server

Tags: c++, g++, aix

I have a socket program server code written in C++.

I'm facing the below error when it is compiled using g++ compiler(OS : Unix AIX). The same code compiled successfully using cc compiler(OS : Unix Sun OS ). Please let me know how to resolve it.

- Code snippet

  ```
  enum sockStates

          {

                  inopen  = ios::in,

                  outopen = ios::out,

                  open    = ios::in | ios::out,

          };
  ```
- Error

  ```
  g++ -gxcoff -maix64 -shared -fpic -fpermissive -w -libstd=c++11ox -I/devt/flex/java/include -I/devt/flex/java/include/aix -I/tmp/ribscomp/server/include -c -o server.o server.cc

   ssocket.h:721:26: error: calls to overloaded operators cannot appear in a constant-expression
      open = ios::in | ios::out,
                           ^
  ```
- g++ version

  ```
  g++ -v
  ```

Using built-in specs.

```
COLLECT_GCC=g++

COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/freeware/libexec/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0/4.8.2/lto-wrapper

Target: powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0

Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.2/configure --with-as=/usr/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --prefix=/opt/freeware --mandir=/opt/freeware/man --infodir=/opt/freeware/info --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-nls --enable-decimal-float=dpd --host=powerpc-ibm-aix7.1.0.0

Thread model: aix

gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, the `|` operator shown in the question is provided by the standard library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that GCC's standard library defines `std::ios::openmode` as an enumeration type with overloaded operators, and in C++03 those operators are not allowed to appear in a constant expression (such as the initializer for an enumerator).

It works with the Solaris compiler because (I assume) `openmode` is just an integral type. The standard allows either, so both compilers are conforming.

In C++11 mode the operators are `constexpr` and can be used here, so one solution is to compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`, but be aware that the ABI for C++11 types is not finalised in GCC 4.8.

Another solution is to replace the enumerators with constant variables:

```
enum sockstates { _max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() };

const sockstates inopen  = ios::in;
const sockstates outopen = ios::out;
const sockstates open    = ios::in | ios::out;
```

Comment: THanks Jonathan . It compiled successfully using g++ with -std=c++11 .

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this regardless of whether there's an error. These are enumerators of type `std::ios_base::openmode` and you want to use this type, not your own enum type. If you really do want to rename/alias standard library entities:

```
namespace sockStates
{
  static const ios::openmode
      inopen  = ios::in,
      outopen = ios::out,
      open    = ios::in | ios::out;
};
```

I would not recommend this though. Just use `ios::in | ios::out` explicitly wherever. An average C++ programmer knows immediately what this means.